# Unable to disable font awesome

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have created Rails app and I am using bootstrap views. I am unable to disable font awesome. The code I have used as follows

```
   <td>
      <%= back_up.db_size %> <a href="<%= back_up.db_link%>"><i class="fa fa-download pull-right p-c-t-4 <%= back_up.db_size == 0  ? 'disabled' : '' %> "></i></a>
   </td>
```

I don't know what was wrong here. I need when page load back_up size will be displayed with download icon, suppose backup size is zero then the size displayed with disabled link.

Comment: Your query is not clear. Please add more to this context!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 <table border=1>
  <td>
    <a href="dsdsd"><i class="fa fa-download pull-right p-c-t-4 not-active" ></i></a>
   </td>
   </td>
<table>
```

CSS

```
.not-active {
        pointer-events: none;
        cursor: default;
        opacity: 0.6;
    }
```

Comment: Glad that helped you. Happy coding @anandh